# Does YARN manages HAWQ master node?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hawq

As we know, HAWQ can register in YARN to get resource by YARN. We can specify the resource used by HAWQ segment nodes. Does YARN manages HAWQ master node?

Answer (score 0):

No, HAWQ master is not managed by Yarn.

Answer (score 0):

For most systems, master is not managed by yarn.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice: Don't install NodeManager of Yarn(to supply containers to other application such as SPARK) on the HAWQ Master Node.

Answer (score 0):

HAWQ master won't be managed by yarn. We don't install nodemanager on the HAWQ master host.

Usually we deploy a cluster like this : hawq segment and yarn nodemanager on the same host, resourcemanager / namenode / snamenode / hawq master / hawq standby on the separate host.

Answer (score 0):

HAWQ master node is not controlled by Resource Manager. SinceYarn manages all the nodes where installs Yarn Node Manager we do not recommend to install Yarn node manager on HAWQ master node, so that Yarn doesn't control HAWQ master.